# No Back/Forward Button with JQuery ScrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, scrollto

I've made a nice page with links that scroll the window to a specific section.  I really like this feature, but it creates an annoyance if you click the links too many times - the back button is clogged with all of the hashtag changes.  I was wondering if it's possible to scroll the page without creating a url for the browser 'back' button to hook on to.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik if you just use   $("#id").scrollTo(); it does not cause url changes.

Assuming you are using the scrollTo plugin....